# Resizing image without losing its quality

Tags: iphone, xcode, uiimagepickercontroller

When i send import images[other images] to server taking less time than iphone images[taking picture through default camera].Is there option to resize an image without losing its quality?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use this code it will help

```
+ (UIImage *)scaleImage:(UIImage *)image maxWidth:(int) maxWidth maxHeight:(int) maxHeight
{
    CGImageRef imgRef = image.CGImage;
    CGFloat width = CGImageGetWidth(imgRef);
    CGFloat height = CGImageGetHeight(imgRef);

    if (width <= maxWidth && height <= maxHeight)
    {
        return image;
    }

    CGAffineTransform transform = CGAffineTransformIdentity;
    CGRect bounds = CGRectMake(0, 0, width, height);

    if (width > maxWidth || height > maxHeight)
    {
        CGFloat ratio = width/height;

        if (ratio > 1)
        {
            bounds.size.width = maxWidth;
            bounds.size.height = bounds.size.width / ratio;
        }
        else
        {
            bounds.size.height = maxHeight;
            bounds.size.width = bounds.size.height * ratio;
        }
    }

    CGFloat scaleRatio = bounds.size.width / width;
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(bounds.size);
    CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
    CGContextScaleCTM(context, scaleRatio, -scaleRatio);
    CGContextTranslateCTM(context, 0, -height);
    CGContextConcatCTM(context, transform);
    CGContextDrawImage(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), CGRectMake(0, 0, width, height), imgRef);

    UIImage *imageCopy = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

    return imageCopy;

}
```

Comment: Did it help? pls elaborate ur question what u actually want to do

Comment: you need to get it from your image remember its diffrent from you imageview height and width.

Comment: it is not working at all. It just rotate the original image

Comment: @amar. Good. But the image is rotated 180 in my side. My image is saved as png. Help me!

Answer (score 2):

try this bellow method ...

Call like bellow...

```
 UIImage *imgBig = [self imageWithImage:yourImage scaledToSize::yourNewImageSize];
```

and use this bellow method..

```
-(UIImage *)imageWithImage:(UIImage*)image scaledToSize:(CGSize)newSize
{

    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(newSize, YES, image.scale);
    [image drawInRect:CGRectMake(0,0,newSize.width,newSize.height)];
    UIImage* newImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
    return newImage;

}
```

Comment: what should be the new image size if I want to preserve the image quality?

Comment: You can set the size with 0.5 ( Half size of the image ) value with the original size of the image for preserve the image quality.